# How can i find out which site the user came from?

Tags: java, http, navigation

Firts: sorry by my english.

And now, my question is:

I want know in what sites the user was before he came to my site.
How can i do that?

If the answers is on java, better =).

Thanks.

Comment: You can look at the `Referer` header in the HTTP request, but it's not guaranteed to be accurate, or even present. Can't help with a Java implementation though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a standard Java servlet, you can do it as follows:

```
public void servletMethod(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    final String referrer = request.getHeader("referer"); 
}
```

Comment: That did not work. Any idea why?

My code:


[code]
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse arg1)
   throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  final String refer = req.getHeader("Referer");
  System.out.println(refer);
 }
[code]

Comment: It must be `referer`, no capital. And as @MikeW said, it's not guaranteed to be there.